# Windows rdp file in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, rdp

How to use Windows `.rdp` file in Ubuntu 14.04. It's not working in Remmina!

I have checked it's working in my local intranet server, only not working in my client server.

Answer (score 0):

You can install xrdp.
And the best solution is to use **Teamviewer** for both **LAN** and **WAN**

Comment: i need via remmina could u please explain @ Priyanka